# Gmail API: Using mailadress containing umlauts results in SMTPEception: The client or server is only configured for addresses with ASCII local-parts

Tags: c#, email, google-api, gmail-api, mimekit

Trying to send an mail with the gmail api to a mail adress that contains umlauts. e.g. büro@gmail.com.
Getting an SmtpException then:

```
maildress: GeneralFailure: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII local-parts: büro@gmail.com.
bei System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetUser(Boolean allowUnicode)
bei System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetAddress(Boolean allowUnicode)
bei System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.GetSmtpAddress(Boolean allowUnicode)
bei System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ValidateUnicodeRequirement(MailMessage message, MailAddressCollection recipients, Boolean allowUnicode)
bei System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

I know that when I usethe .net smtp client directly you can set SmtpDeliveryFormat.International to be able to. But how to set it when I use the gmail api?

```
private GmailService _service;

public void SendMail(MailMessage message)
{
    message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    MimeKit.MimeMessage mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(message);
    Message sendMmessage = new Message {Raw = Base64UrlEncode(mimeMessage)};

    _service.Users.Messages.Send(sendMmessage, _fromMailAdress).Execute();
}
```

Since I use a google business account I can't use the SMTPClient directly, because google shut down the usage of less secure apps.

Comment: See following : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/gmail/v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the [IdnMapping class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.globalization.idnmapping?view=netframework-4.8)

```
IdnMapping idn = new IdnMapping();

MailMessage message = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress(_fromMailAdress),
};
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.To.Add(idn.GetAscii(toMailAdress));
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = content;
```

büro@gmail.com would resolve into xn--bro-hoa@gmail.com